# Querying PHPMYADMIN with two constraints

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I am trying to create a login script that pulls information by verifying that the username is part of a group. In other words i am using two "ands" to verify info. Am i doing this correctly?

```
 PHP:

$check = mysql_query("SELECT username ,password FROM customers WHERE username =                     '".$_POST['user_name']."' and group_name='".$group_name."'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: make sure you use mysql_real_escape_string or something similar before using this.  otherwise it does look correct.

Comment: Hmm. You might want to read up on SQL injection attacks, among other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Brandon Horsley** and **Matt Gibson** already mentioned it as comments - think about `SQL injection`. Next thing is that I strongly **don't recommend** to use `die(mysql_error())`. Otherwise an experienced user might be able to "read something" out of that.
The easiest way is to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` (http://de.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) - so you could adapt your code just like that (I assume that `$group_name` is also a value that can be manipulated by user):

```
<?php
// ...
$check = mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM customers WHERE username = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']) ."' and group_name = '". mysql_real_escape_string($group_name) ."'") or die('error);
// ...
?>
```